# USB devices in dock disconnecting on notification ( Lenovo X1 Carbon gen 7 )

Tags: usb, sound, dmesg

When receiving a Chromium notification from slack, or sometimes just playing sound from Spotify, ubuntu will disconnect all USB devices connected to my Thunderbolt 3 dock. Charging is working.

dmesg output, immediately after disconnect when triggered by slack notification:

```
...
[61217.493105] input: Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:05:00.0/0000:0
6:01.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:02.0/0000:0a:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.1/5-2.1.1.2/5-2.1.1.2:1.3/0003:17EF:3083.006E/input/inp
ut253                                                                                                                     
[61217.550611] hid-generic 0003:17EF:3083.006E: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock US
B Audio] on usb-0000:0a:00.0-2.1.1.2/input3                                                                               
[61220.374778] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[61220.602687] usb 5-2.4.1: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd   
[61220.830779] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[61224.235317] pcieport 0000:05:00.0: BAR 13: [io  0x0000-0x1fff] has bogus alignment
[61224.235329] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: BAR 13: [io  0x0000-0x0fff] has bogus alignment
[61224.534076] mce: CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 6339)
[61224.534077] mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 6339)
[61224.534078] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[61224.534079] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[61224.534128] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[61224.534128] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[61224.534129] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13673)
[61224.534130] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13673)
[61224.534131] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[61224.534132] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[61224.546077] mce: CPU7: Core temperature/speed normal
[61224.546078] mce: CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[61224.546079] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546079] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546129] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546130] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546131] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546131] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546132] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[61224.546132] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[61306.444633] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 36
[61306.444639] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe5c6d0 trb-start 00000000ffe5c6e0 trb-end 00000000ffe5c6e0 seg-start 00000000ffe5c000 seg-end 00000000ffe5cff0
[61306.794372] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[61306.794387] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe5dcc0 trb-start 00000000ffe5dcd0 trb-end 00000000ffe5dcd0 seg-start 00000000ffe5d000 seg-end 00000000ffe5dff0
[61306.915653] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[61306.915671] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe5c450 trb-start 00000000ffe5c460 trb-end 00000000ffe5c460 seg-start 00000000ffe5c000 seg-end 00000000ffe5cff0
[61307.026714] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[61307.026733] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe5cb30 trb-start 00000000ffe5cb40 trb-end 00000000ffe5cb40 seg-start 00000000ffe5c000 seg-end 00000000ffe5cff0
[61307.227884] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 36
[61307.227893] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe5d7c0 trb-start 00000000ffe5d7d0 trb-end 00000000ffe5d7d0 seg-start 00000000ffe5d000 seg-end 00000000ffe5dff0
[61307.846899] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[61318.030332] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
[61318.030343] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[61318.030380] r8152 6-2.1.2:1.0 enx3ce1a1c12f45: Stop submitting intr, status -108
[61318.030381] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[61318.030540] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[61318.030942] psmouse serio1: TrackPoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[61318.031120] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[61318.031121] usb 5-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[61318.031123] usb 5-2.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[61318.031124] usb 5-2.1.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[61318.031164] usb 6-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[61318.031165] usb 6-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[61318.031166] usb 6-2.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[61318.115509] usb 5-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 0
[61318.154330] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
[61318.255618] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
[61318.446326] usb 5-2.3: device not accepting address 4, error -22
[61318.446363] usb 5-2.4.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[61318.835220] usb 5-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[61318.835638] usb 5-2.5: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

dmesg output, immediately after trying to play music on Spotify:

```
[62155.184943] usb 5-2.1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=3083, bcdDevice= 0.90
[62155.184944] usb 5-2.1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[62155.184945] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Product: ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio
[62155.184946] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[62155.184946] usb 5-2.1.1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[62155.190184] usb 6-2.1.2: reset SuperSpeedPlus Gen 2 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[62155.218814] r8152 6-2.1.2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Invalid header when reading pass-thru MAC addr
[62155.254318] r8152 6-2.1.2:1.0 eth0: v1.10.11
[62155.289243] r8152 6-2.1.2:1.0 enx3ce1a1c12f45: renamed from eth0
[62155.325018] input: Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:05:00.0/0000:0
6:01.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:02.0/0000:0a:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.1/5-2.1.1.2/5-2.1.1.2:1.3/0003:17EF:3083.0072/input/inp
ut261
[62155.382106] hid-generic 0003:17EF:3083.0072: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock US
B Audio] on usb-0000:0a:00.0-2.1.1.2/input3
[62155.516447] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81 
[62156.883724] thinkpad_acpi: undocked from hotplug port replicator
[62156.916457] retire_capture_urb: 229 callbacks suppressed
[62157.003297] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[62157.003310] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe1cae0 trb-start 00000000ffe1caf0 trb-end 00000000ff
e1caf0 seg-start 00000000ffe1c000 seg-end 00000000ffe1cff0
[62158.142185] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[62158.430208] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[62159.354927] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 36
[62159.354940] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe1be50 trb-start 00000000ffe1be60 trb-end 00000000ff
e1be60 seg-start 00000000ffe1b000 seg-end 00000000ffe1bff0
[62159.665158] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[62159.665170] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe1b1d0 trb-start 00000000ffe1b1e0 trb-end 00000000ff
e1b1e0 seg-start 00000000ffe1b000 seg-end 00000000ffe1bff0
[62159.974076] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[62160.270119] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[62160.401549] mce: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1918)
[62160.401550] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[62160.401551] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1918)
[62160.401551] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13674)
[62160.401552] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13675)
[62160.401552] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13675)
[62160.401588] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13675)
[62160.401589] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13675)
[62160.401590] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13675)
[62160.401591] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13675)
[62160.401788] mce: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
[62160.401789] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401790] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401790] mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[62160.401791] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401791] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401792] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401793] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401826] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[62160.401826] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[62367.562912] kauditd_printk_skb: 397 callbacks suppressed
[62367.562913] audit: type=1400 audit(1592989236.294:135): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/core/9289/
usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=212543 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[62371.035248] audit: type=1107 audit(1592989239.766:136): pid=1195 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="state" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=212543 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1198 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[62371.885140] audit: type=1107 audit(1592989240.614:137): pid=1195 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="state" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=212543 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1198 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[62385.225157] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 36
[62385.225170] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe1bdb0 trb-start 00000000ffe1bdc0 trb-end 00000000ffe1bdc0 seg-start 00000000ffe1b000 seg-end 00000000ffe1bff0
[62385.945794] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[62385.945807] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe1cae0 trb-start 00000000ffe1caf0 trb-end 00000000ffe1caf0 seg-start 00000000ffe1c000 seg-end 00000000ffe1cff0
[62386.076696] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[62386.076711] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000ffe1b310 trb-start 00000000ffe1b320 trb-end 00000000ffe1b320 seg-start 00000000ffe1b000 seg-end 00000000ffe1bff0
[62386.301688] usb 5-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[62389.985310] usb 5-2.1.1.2: timeout: still 3 active urbs on EP #1
[62390.985250] usb 5-2.1.1.2: timeout: still 3 active urbs on EP #1
[62394.117320] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[62394.117336] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[62394.117474] r8152 6-2.1.2:1.0 enx3ce1a1c12f45: Stop submitting intr, status -108
[62394.117479] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[62394.117501] usb 5-2-port3: cannot reset (err = -22)
[62394.117542] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0
[62394.117546] usb 5-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[62394.117555] usb 5-2.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[62394.117563] usb 5-2.1.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[62394.117701] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[62394.117779] usb 6-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[62394.117784] usb 6-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[62394.117788] usb 6-2.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[62394.137298] audit: type=1107 audit(1592989262.870:138): pid=1195 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=212543 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1198 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[62394.142069] audit: type=1107 audit(1592989262.874:139): pid=1195 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="DeviceRemoved" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=212543 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1198 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[62394.145848] audit: type=1107 audit(1592989262.878:140): pid=1195 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=212543 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1198 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[62394.149051] audit: type=1107 audit(1592989262.878:141): pid=1195 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=212543 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1198 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[62394.217843] usb 5-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[62394.889588] usb 5-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[62394.889591] usb 5-2.4.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[62395.313661] usb 5-2.5: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too on a P1 Gen2 (very similar hardware) with a Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Workstation Dock.

Earlier today, I logged-on into Windows 10 and updated all firmware and BIOS of the laptop, as well as all firmware of the dock. I did not see the issue happen again for a few hours, in Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't confirm it is gone - it comes and goes after all. [READ UPDATE BELOW]

The workwarounds that people recommended to me so far are:

1. Limit the network to 100mb/s supposedly helps:

   `ethtool eth..... speed 100 duplex full autoneg on`
2. Reloading the Realtek kernel module r8152 and restarting the network-manager also fixes the problem temporary:

   ```
   sudo rmmod r8152.ko
   sudo modprobe r8152.ko
   sudo service network-manager restart
   ```

---

Update: none of the workarounds worked for me.
The latest ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Workstation Dock firmware V3.1.66 made things much worse - I can't use multiple monitors, and I can't login to the system with the Dock connected. If I connect it after logging in, the USB hub doesn't work. It's just broken.

There is no way to downgrade the firmware, sadly.

I am going to return the Dock.